# My service.ts not invoked in my component?

Tags: typescript, angular8

In my angular project, I have a home component. in that component, I have a method. so I have a service.ts and I import that service in my homecomponent.ts file. I have a method like fliterclicked and condition in service.ts file. but while running when I click the method I got this error - 'fliterclicked' not a function

Homecomponent.html:

```
<button (click)="filterClicked()"
        [class.active]="filterChanged"
        id="filterDropdown" type="button"
        class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-clear-default job-filter"></button>
```

homecomponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterService } from "../../services/filter.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'jobs-sub-header',
  templateUrl: './sub-header.component.html',
  providers:  [ FilterService ]
})
export class SubHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private filterService: FilterService) {
}
```

my service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
   filterClicked(){
      this.filterShow = !this.filterShow;
   }
 }
```

I don't know where I missed..please anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly calling filterClicked() from html only check your component methods. So you have to mention it like `filterService.filterService()` in your Homecomponent.html. Make your service as public in your ts constructor.

homecomponent.ts

```
constructor(
    public filterService: FilterService) {
}
```

Homecomponent.html:

```
<button (click)="filterService.filterClicked()"
        [class.active]="filterChanged"
        id="filterDropdown" type="button"
        class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-clear-default job-filter"></button>
```

Comment: thanks. it's working. but one more doubt onclick method I want to do hide and show in different components using services...how to do that? any idea?

Comment: In service, create a boolean variable and use that in your HTML to show and hide the components. on click, you can change that boolean whatever component you need to show.